# Extracting the values from Apache Solr in the required format. Any better way of doing it

Tags: solr

When we fire the query with nested facets we get the output in raw format and after that we have to do lot of processing to convert the raw data into the UI required format.
We are doing complex processing to read the 
    SimpleOrderedMap
and create our own datastructure.
Is there any template based approach where we define it and solr will give the output in the required format.
I googled out but not able to find any approach.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet would be trying with [VelocityResponseWriter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Response+Writers#ResponseWriters-VelocityResponseWriter), that uses Velocity templating engine. Not a lot of people use it though, I think.

Also, from your question, I understand by 'raw format' you mean javabin format? If so, did you try json output?